# mongoose find() Query with ObjectID returning no results

Tags: mongoose

```
function testObjectId() {
    var id="5f2505539a54bb9009c6594e";
    var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

    SSProduct.find(
    {
        _id:ObjectId(id)
    },
    function (err, list) {
            console.log("result",list)

    });

}
```

this above function is not returning any value although I gave the _id value which is available in collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, when I define schema, I had mentioned _id as String

```
var SSProductSchema = new Schema({
    //_id: String,  //We should not define this as String here
    ProductName: String,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the _id is created by the mongoDB database. You don't have to specify it, not even as a String. You can still use the query methods to find the data.

Your solution worked because you basically removed that key.

Comment: _id is created by mongoldb by default as object Id. But if we specify the type as string mongoose will treat as string, while actual value in db is objectID. Your comment "Your solution worked because you basically removed that key."==> is not true.

Comment: So the original code was basically overwriting the key "_id"? And so mongoldb had trouble figuring that out?

Comment: no. _id was getting created in mongodb( data base ) as usual in Object ID. The issue was only in mongoose typecasting to String. ie. DB content was ok, only issue when try to retrieve using mongoose query